# Postfix: newaliases fails at postfix service startup due to aliases.db permission problems

Tags: linux, email, postfix, systemd, gentoo

I recently started migrating my mail server to systemd.

I have an alias hash map:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
```

When starting the service:

```
systemctl restart postfix
```

newalias and postalias complain about the permissions of my aliases.db whatever permissions I set:

```
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-07-22 00:36:08 CEST; 22ms ago
    Process: 299515 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/newaliases (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 299518 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 299596 (master)
        CPU: 721ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
             ├─299596 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
             ├─299597 pickup -l -t unix -u
             └─299598 qmgr -l -t unix -u

jul 22 00:36:07 rulakir systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
jul 22 00:36:07 rulakir newaliases[299515]: postalias: fatal: open /etc/postfix/aliases.db: Read-only file system
jul 22 00:36:07 rulakir postfix/postalias[299515]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/aliases.db: Read-only file system
jul 22 00:36:08 rulakir postfix/postfix-script[299582]: warning: group or other writable: /etc/postfix/./aliases.db
jul 22 00:36:08 rulakir postfix/postfix-script[299594]: starting the Postfix mail system
jul 22 00:36:08 rulakir postfix/master[299596]: daemon started -- version 3.5.1, configuration /etc/postfix
jul 22 00:36:08 rulakir systemd[1]: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
```

It complains that it read only, but if I change group or owner to postfix it complains that it should be owned by root and/or that it has write permissions. What permissions should I give to `aliases` and `aliases.db`?

Comment: The permissions are not the problem, the read only file system is the problem! Check your logs to find out why the filesystem is read only.

Comment: The file system is not read-only, everything resides on my root partition which is mounted rw and working properly. Or is postfix somehow sandboxed in systemd?

Comment: OK, then why does it complain that your filesystem is read only?

Comment: To clarify: newaliases and postalias seem to work outside of service.

Comment: Yes, that is a good question. Are you sure it's not complaining about the file specifically?

Comment: Is this a Debian-based system? It looks like it might be. That could be part of the issue. Debian based distros do a lot of strange things.

Comment: Is the hash database file counted as its own file system?

Comment: Not that I've ever seen. It's just another ordinary file.

Comment: No I don't think it's based on Debian, Gentoo is its own thing.

Comment: Gentoo? OK, that's an unusual choice. I'm not sure how much help most of us can be with that.

Comment: Based on the Gentoo [systemd service](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/mail-mta/postfix/files/postfix.service), I'm guessing one of the hardening options is messing with `newaliases`. Are your running `~amd64` or is this a stable system?

Comment: To be fair, based on systemd's documentations, the restrictions should work, I'd suggest disabling them to validate that's the issue and filing a bug on bugs.gentoo.org if it is.

Comment: Stable system. Only running ~amd64 on smartmontools. What restrictions are those? I'm not running  hardened or something like that.
I also ran fsck. It seemed to fix something, but still same problem.

Comment: Wow, so it IS sandboxed! **ProtectSystem "If set to "full", the /etc directory is mounted read-only, too."**

Comment: @Ginnungagap: Not tested yet, but if you want to write an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I'll write a more complete one in a bit, I'm on mobile right now, but the ReadWritePaths should enable writing to the aliases only it seems to have been moved to `/etc/mail` instead of `/etc/postfix`

Comment: No need to change the unit, I moved the databases out of `/etc/postfix` to `/var/lib/postfix` and everything is happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gentoo mail-mta/postfix package's [systemd service](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/mail-mta/postfix/files/postfix.service) unit includes hardening options by default which do indeed sandbox the service. Specifically:

```
ProtectSystem=full
ReadWritePaths=-/etc/mail/aliases.db
```

Despite the additional sandboxing, the `/etc/mail/aliases.db` file should be writable thanks to the `ReadWritePaths`. From the systemd.exec man page:

> ProtectSystem=
>
> Takes a boolean argument or the special values "full" or "strict". <...> If set to "full", the /etc directory is mounted read-only, too.

> ReadWritePaths=
>
> Paths listed in ReadWritePaths= are accessible from within the namespace with the same access modes as from outside of it.
>
> Paths in ReadWritePaths=, ReadOnlyPaths= and InaccessiblePaths= may be prefixed with "-", in which case they will be ignored when they do not exist.

Based on the latest stable mail-mta/postfix ebuild (3.5.1) as of this writing, `src_prepare` includes `sed -i -e "/^#define ALIAS_DB_MAP/s|:/etc/aliases|:/etc/mail/aliases|"` to set the default location of the alias map at the appropriate location. Yet from your logs, yours seem to point to `/etc/postfix/aliases.db`. I'd suggest leaving the default of `/etc/mail/aliases.db` or overriding the `ReadWritePaths` using `systemctl edit postfix.service` appropriately.

Comment: As the entire `/etc` was write protected `by default, I put them in `/var/lib/postfix` instead and it is happy.